# 500 internal server Symfony on production, possibly due to PHPsuexec

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, suexec

Running into a 500 internal server error on my subdomain installation of Symfony when I attempt to visit any modules. The server does have PHPsuexec installed on it. Does anybody know whats up? Otherwise it states that the symfony project is installed and it runs fine on my server.

One glitch could be that on my server the directories have permissions 777 and all files have 666 permissions. However, courtesy of PHPsuexec, most my directories seem to have 775 and the files a 664 permission level.

Thanks  all!

Parijat

Comment: What do the error logs have to say? Why ask people to guess when you can look up the actual reason?

Comment: hey Pekka, where can I look up the error logs (still learning), I did not upload the log folder that comes along with the Symfony directory !

Comment: The web server should have a `error.log` file somewhere in the system. On a *nix system, I think the standard location is `/var/log`

Comment: @pekka, thanks....this is on a production server, it is a *nix system but don't see any /var folder to probe this info

Answer (score 1):

My guesses would be:

1. Check if you have enabled mod_rewrite and your htaccess file (strong chances to be it)
2. Change the no_script to true in your production environment ($sf_root/apps/app_name/config/settings.yml) , clear cache and try again
3. Try using the php symfony proj:perm on your project after trying everything else.

Hope this helps

Comment: HI guiman, don't these require access to the command line? I do not have the command line on me, but I guess I can delete the contents of the cache folder?

Comment: Yeap, thats another way to go with it! Try it and let me know

Comment: Your number one is impossible to understand. Do you mean "check and if it's enabled disable it" or "check and enable it"?

Answer (score 0):

PHPsuexec servers do not allow directory permissions to be 'looser' than 0755 and file permissions cannot be 'looser' than 0644. Check the permissions set on all the dirs and files in the symfony installation, and modify to meet this requirement.

Next, symfony has permissions of 0777 & 0666 hard-coded into its files. You must change these permissions in symfony's code so that symfony does not make the permissions 'too loose' on dirs and files in the future.

Please read this documentation: http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/SymfonyPHPsuexec

Long discussion here: http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/45845/index.html